# Error while launching the eks cluster node group related to security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have taken inspiration from https://github.com/boldlink/terraform-aws-eks/blob/main/modules/managed-node-group/main.tf

my node_group.tf looks like

```
### Eks node group
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "main" {
  cluster_name           = var.cluster_name
  node_role_arn          = aws_iam_role.node_group.arn
  subnet_ids             = var.node_group_subnet_ids
  ami_type               = var.ami_type
  capacity_type          = var.capacity_type
  disk_size              = var.create_custom_launch_template ? null : var.disk_size
  force_update_version   = var.force_update_version
  instance_types         = var.instance_types
  labels                 = var.labels
  node_group_name        = var.node_group_name_prefix != null ? null : coalesce(var.node_group_name, var.cluster_name)
  node_group_name_prefix = var.node_group_name != null ? null : var.node_group_name_prefix
  release_version        = var.release_version
  tags                   = merge({ Name = "${var.cluster_name}-node-group" }, module.variables.tags)
  version                = var.kubernetes_version
    
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.desired_size
    max_size     = var.max_size
    min_size     = var.min_size
  }
    
  dynamic "update_config" {
    for_each = length(var.update_config) > 0 ? [var.update_config] : []
    content {
      max_unavailable            = try(update_config.value.max_unavailable, null)
      max_unavailable_percentage = try(update_config.value.max_unavailable_percentage, null)
    }
  }
    
  dynamic "launch_template" {
    for_each = var.create_custom_launch_template ? [1] : []
    content {
      id      = local.launch_template_id
      version = local.launch_template_version
    }
  }
    
  dynamic "taint" {
    for_each = var.taints
    content {
      key    = taint.value.key
      value  = try(taint.value.value, null)
      effect = taint.value.effect
    }
  }
    
  timeouts {
    create = lookup(var.timeouts, "create", "60m")
    update = lookup(var.timeouts, "update", "60m")
    delete = lookup(var.timeouts, "delete", "60m")
  }
}
    
resource "aws_launch_template" "main" {
  count                   = var.create_custom_launch_template ? 1 : 0
  name                    = "${var.cluster_name}-custom-template"
  description             = var.launch_template_description
  ebs_optimized           = var.ebs_optimized
  image_id                = var.image_id
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  user_data               = var.install_ssm_agent ? data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered : var.user_data
  #vpc_security_group_ids = length(var.network_interfaces) > 0 ? [] : concat([aws_security_group.node_group.id], var.security_group_ids)
  #vpc_security_group_ids  = length(var.network_interfaces) > 0 ? [] : var.security_group_ids
  vpc_security_group_ids  = length(var.network_interfaces) > 0 ? [] : [aws_security_group.node_group.id]
  default_version         = var.default_version
  disable_api_termination = var.disable_api_termination
  kernel_id               = var.kernel_id
  ram_disk_id             = var.ram_disk_id
   
  dynamic "block_device_mappings" {
    for_each = var.block_device_mappings
    content {
      device_name  = try(block_device_mappings.value.device_name, null)
      no_device    = try(block_device_mappings.value.no_device, null)
      virtual_name = try(block_device_mappings.value.virtual_name, null)
    
      dynamic "ebs" {
        for_each = flatten([try(block_device_mappings.value.ebs, [])])
        content {
          delete_on_termination = try(ebs.value.delete_on_termination, null)
          encrypted             = try(ebs.value.encrypted, null)
          kms_key_id            = try(ebs.value.kms_key_id, var.create_kms ? aws_kms_key.this[0].arn : null)
          iops                  = try(ebs.value.iops, null)
          throughput            = try(ebs.value.throughput, null)
          snapshot_id           = try(ebs.value.snapshot_id, null)
          volume_size           = try(ebs.value.volume_size, null)
          volume_type           = try(ebs.value.volume_type, null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  dynamic "capacity_reservation_specification" {
    for_each = length(var.capacity_reservation_specification) > 0 ? [var.capacity_reservation_specification] : []
     content {
       capacity_reservation_preference = try(capacity_reservation_specification.value.capacity_reservation_preference, null)
    
      dynamic "capacity_reservation_target" {
        for_each = try([capacity_reservation_specification.value.capacity_reservation_target], [])
         content {
           capacity_reservation_id                 = try(capacity_reservation_target.value.capacity_reservation_id, null)
            capacity_reservation_resource_group_arn = try(capacity_reservation_target.value.capacity_reservation_resource_group_arn, null)
         }
       }
     }
   }
    
   dynamic "cpu_options" {
    for_each = length(var.cpu_options) > 0 ? [var.cpu_options] : []
    content {
      core_count       = cpu_options.value.core_count
      threads_per_core = cpu_options.value.threads_per_core
    }
  }
    
  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = var.cpu_credits
  }
    
  dynamic "elastic_gpu_specifications" {
    for_each = length(var.elastic_gpu_specifications) > 0 ? [var.elastic_gpu_specifications] : []
    content {
      type = elastic_gpu_specifications.value.type
    }
  }
    
  dynamic "enclave_options" {
    for_each = length(var.enclave_options) > 0 ? [var.enclave_options] : []
    content {
      enabled = enclave_options.value.enabled
    }
  }
    
  dynamic "license_specification" {
    for_each = length(var.license_specifications) > 0 ? [var.license_specifications] : []
    content {
      license_configuration_arn = license_specifications.value.license_configuration_arn
    }
  }
  
  dynamic "metadata_options" {
    for_each = length(keys(var.metadata_options)) > 0 ? [var.metadata_options] : []
    content {
      http_endpoint               = try(metadata_options.value.http_endpoint, null)
      http_protocol_ipv6          = try(metadata_options.value.http_protocol_ipv6, null)
      http_put_response_hop_limit = try(metadata_options.value.http_put_response_hop_limit, null)
      http_tokens                 = try(metadata_options.value.http_tokens, null)
      instance_metadata_tags      = try(metadata_options.value.instance_metadata_tags, null)
    }
  }
    
  monitoring {
    enabled = var.enable_monitoring
  }
    
  dynamic "network_interfaces" {
    for_each = var.network_interfaces
      content {
        associate_carrier_ip_address = try(network_interfaces.value.associate_carrier_ip_address, null)
        associate_public_ip_address  = try(network_interfaces.value.associate_public_ip_address, null)
        delete_on_termination        = try(network_interfaces.value.delete_on_termination, false)
        description                  = try(network_interfaces.value.description, null)
        device_index                 = try(network_interfaces.value.device_index, null)
        interface_type               = try(network_interfaces.value.interface_type, null)
        ipv4_prefix_count            = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_prefixes, null) != null ? null : try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_prefix_count, null)
        ipv4_prefixes                = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_prefixes, null)
        ipv4_addresses               = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_addresses, null)
        ipv4_address_count           = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_addresses, null) != null ? null : try(network_interfaces.value.ipv4_address_count, null)
        ipv6_prefix_count            = length(try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_prefixes, [])) > 0 ? null : try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_prefix_count, null)
        ipv6_prefixes                = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_prefixes, [])
        ipv6_addresses               = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_addresses, null)
        ipv6_address_count           = try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_addresses, null) != null ? null : try(network_interfaces.value.ipv6_address_count, null)
        network_interface_id         = try(network_interfaces.value.network_interface_id, null)
        network_card_index           = try(network_interfaces.value.network_card_index, null)
        private_ip_address           = try(network_interfaces.value.private_ip_address, null)
        # security_groups              = compact(concat(try(network_interfaces.value.security_groups, []), aws_security_group.node_group.id))
        # security_groups              = compact(concat(try(network_interfaces.value.security_groups, []), var.security_group_ids, [aws_security_group.node_group.id]))
        security_groups              = compact(concat(try(network_interfaces.value.security_groups, []), [aws_security_group.node_group.id])) 
     }
   }
    
   dynamic "placement" {
     for_each = length(var.placement) > 0 ? [var.placement] : []
     content {
       affinity                = lookup(placement.value, "affinity", null)
       availability_zone       = lookup(placement.value, "availability_zone", null)
       group_name              = lookup(placement.value, "group_name", null)
       host_id                 = lookup(placement.value, "host_id", null)
       host_resource_group_arn = lookup(placement.value, "host_resource_group_arn", null)
       spread_domain           = lookup(placement.value, "spread_domain", null)
       tenancy                 = lookup(placement.value, "tenancy", null)
       partition_number        = lookup(placement.value, "partition_number", null)
      }
    }
    
    dynamic "private_dns_name_options" {
      for_each = length(var.private_dns_name_options) > 0 ? [var.private_dns_name_options] : []
      content {
        enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record = lookup(private_dns_name_options.value, "enable_resource_name_dns_aaaa_record", null)
        enable_resource_name_dns_a_record    = lookup(private_dns_name_options.value, "enable_resource_name_dns_a_record", null)
        hostname_type                        = private_dns_name_options.value.hostname_type
      }
    }
    
    dynamic "tag_specifications" {
      for_each = var.tag_specifications
      content {
       resource_type = try(tag_specifications.value.resource_type, "volume")
       tags          = module.variables.tags
      }
    }
    
    lifecycle {
      create_before_destroy = true
    }
    
    depends_on = [
     aws_iam_role.node_group
    ]
}
```

my sg.tf looks like

```
# Node Security Group
resource "aws_security_group" "node_group" {
  name        = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.node_group_name}-node-group-sg"
  description = "Security group for all nodes in the cluster"
  vpc_id      = var.vpc_id
  tags = merge(module.variables.tags, {
    "Name"                                      = "${var.cluster_name}-${var.node_group_name}-node-group-sg"
    "kubernetes.io/cluster/${var.cluster_name}" = "owned"
  })
    
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_https" {
  description              = "Allow node to communicate with control plane"
  from_port                = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  to_port                  = 443
  type                     = "egress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_dns" {
  description              = "Allow node to communicate with control plane"
  from_port                = 53
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  to_port                  = 53
  type                     = "egress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_tcp" {
  description              = "Allow node to communicate with control plane"
  from_port                = 10250
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  to_port                  = 10250
  type                     = "egress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node_ingress_self" {
  description              = "Allow node to communicate with each other"
  from_port                = 0
  protocol                 = "-1"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node_ingress_cluster" {
  description              = "Allow worker Kubelets and pods to receive communication from the cluster control plane"
  from_port                = 1025
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  to_port                  = 65535
  type                     = "ingress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "node_ingress_cluster_https" {
  description              = "Allow incoming https connections from the EKS masters security group"
  from_port                = 443
  to_port                  = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = aws_security_group.node_group.id
  source_security_group_id = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  type                     = "ingress"
}
    
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "cluster_ingress_node_https" {
  description              = "Allow pods to communicate with the cluster API Server"
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 443
  to_port                  = 443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = var.eks_cluster_security_group
  source_security_group_id = aws_security_group.node_group.id
}
```

I am getting error

> aws_eks_node_group.main" error: creating EKS Node Group (test-eks-dev:managed0): operation error EKS: CreateNodegroup, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 0b802863-0055-4349-bb79-ba22dc640393, InvalidRequestException: You do not have access to a default security group in VPC vpc-xxx. Specify a security group, and try again.

I have specified the security group in my code.

Comment: How are the the security group code and EKS code connected? Are they a part of the same root module? Also, is the VPC ID the ID of the default VPC? If so, you would need to make changes to the arguments you use in the launch template.

Comment: yes they are part of the same module. VPC ID is not ID of the default vpc. Can you point out what I am doing wrong ?